# When is a special lock file or opening file in 'c' mode necessary with PHP flock?

Tags: php, file, locking

Quoting from the [PHP flock documentation](http://www.php.net/flock):

> Because **flock()** requires a file pointer, you may have to use a special
>   lock file to protect access to a file that you intend to truncate by
>   opening it in write mode (with a "w" or "w+" argument to fopen()).

Quoting from the [PHP fopen documentation](http://www.php.net/fopen):

> **'c'** -- Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is
>   created. If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to **'w'**),
>   nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with **'x'**). The
>   file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file. This may be
>   useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see flock()) before
>   attempting to modify the file, as using **'w'** could truncate the file
>   before the lock was obtained (if truncation is desired, ftruncate()
>   can be used after the lock is requested).

I am trying to understand what the issue is with getting an advisory lock with `flock` after a file has been truncated by opening it with `fopen` in `'w'` mode. In what scenario one would want to use a special lock file to protect access to a file that one intends to truncate by opening it in write mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realized the answer to this question while typing the question, so
I'll post my answer as well. Obtaining an advisory lock on a file after
truncating it could be a problem when another reader script is trying to read
the file. The reader script would encounter a truncated file (an empty file)
if it happens to read the file between the time at which the writer
script opened the file in `'w'` mode and the time at which it acquired
a lock on the file.

Here are two scripts that demonstrate the issue. The first script writes
its PID into a file called foo.txt. The second script attempts to read
the PID from this file.

**write.php:**

```
<?php
$f = fopen('foo.txt', 'w');

sleep(5); // Artificial delay between open and lock

flock($f, LOCK_EX);
fwrite($f, getmypid() . "\n");
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
?>
```

**read.php:**

```
<?php
$f = fopen('foo.txt', 'r');
flock($f, LOCK_EX);

$size = filesize('foo.txt');
echo ($size === 0 ? "File is empty\n" : fread($f, $size));

flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
?>
```

The following shell session shows that read.php finds an empty file
when it tries to read the file after write.php opened the file and
before write.php acquired a lock on the file.

```
$ php write.php < /dev/null &
[1] 17511
$ for i in {1..10}; do php read.php; sleep 1; done
File is empty
File is empty
File is empty
File is empty
File is empty
[1]+  Done                    php write.php < /dev/null
17511
17511
17511
17511
17511
```

This issue occurs because we acquire a lock on the file after it has been truncated. That's a little too late. We want to first acquire a lock and then perform truncation or any other modification on it. There are two ways to do this.

#### Use a special lock file

**write2.php:**

```
<?php
$lock = fopen('foo.lock', 'w');

sleep(5); // Artificial delay between open and lock

flock($lock, LOCK_EX);
$f = fopen('foo.txt', 'w');
fwrite($f, getmypid() . "\n");
fclose($f);
flock($lock, LOCK_UN);
?>
```

The following shell session shows that read.php never encountered a
truncated file.

```
$ php write2.php < /dev/null &
[1] 17533
$ for i in {1..10}; do php read.php; sleep 1; done
17511
17511
17511
17511
17511
[1]+  Done                    php write2.php < /dev/null
17533
17533
17533
17533
17533
```

#### Open file in `'c'` mode and then lock it

**write3.php:**

```
<?php
$f = fopen('foo.txt', 'c');

sleep(5); // Artificial delay between open and lock

flock($f, LOCK_EX);
ftruncate($f, 0);
fwrite($f, getmypid() . "\n");
flock($f, LOCK_UN);

fclose($f);
?>
```

This script takes advantage of the fact that opening the file in `'c'` mode does not truncate the file automatially, so now we can truncate the file with `ftruncate` after we have acquired a lock on it and before writing to it. As a result read.php never encounters a truncated file.

```
$ php write3.php < /dev/null &
[1] 17558
$ for i in {1..10}; do php read.php; sleep 1; done
17533
17533
17533
17533
17533
[1]+  Done                    php write3.php < /dev/null
17558
17558
17558
17558
17558
```